# Find yearly events (dates of birthdays) that occur later in the year than today

Tags: mysql, date

My MySQL table:

```
+---------------+----------------+
| name          | birthdate      |
+---------------+----------------+
| John Doe      | 1984-01-15     |
| Susan Akroy   | 1987-01-30     |
+---------------+----------------+
```

`Today = 2015-01-27`

The PHP:

```
$curDate = date("Y-m-d");
$sql = 'select id,name,birthdate from people where birthdate >= '{$curDate}',  order by birthdate asc'
```

I'm trying to write a MySQL query that looks at someone's birthdate and if the month and date of that birthdate (disregarding the year) are today or in the future it will return the person's details.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Show your actual query. We can't fix what we can't see.

Comment: add your query details

Comment: Dagon's solution will work, assuming `birthdate` has type `DATE`... but of course, it should :)

Comment: If a birthdate is larger than today, the person is not yet born ... :)

Comment: Let me rephrase my question...

Comment: to early in the morning ;-)

Comment: It appears that `DATE_FORMAT` is the MySQL function I can use. I'll still be testing it for a few days. If it gives the required result I will post the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by sorting the data.  This is rather tricky, because you have to handle end-of-year issues.

Here is a reasonable way:

```
select t.*
from table t
order by (format(birthdate, '%m-%d') >= format(now(), '%m-%d') desc,
         format(birthdate, '%m-%d')  asc
```

You can then add `limit` to get a particular number.

Comment: This answer does not seem to take into account when passing a year.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer . . .It does now, that the second key is the month and day without the year.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a `DATE` object to store your birthdate field you can do something like:

```
Select * from table_name where WHERE birthdate >= CURDATE()
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE 
MONTH(birthdate ) = desired_month AND 
DAY(birthdate ) = desired_day
```

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the near future to be 10 days:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),
DATE(YEAR(NOW())+'-'+MONTH(birthdate)+'-'+DAY(birthdate))
) BETWEEN 0 AND 10
```

Comment: This returns `#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'MAKEDATE'`

Comment: fixed it, using `DATE()` function instead

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question. There are two problems we must solve:

1. Take into account when the two dates are not in the same year.
2. Take into account leap year : usually 1st march comes 10 days after february 19th, but 11 days for leap years.

The following query looks somehow scary, but it works (tested on real data). It selects all peaople that have a birthdate between today and today + 10 days.

```
select id, name, birthdate,
date_format(concat(year(now()), date_format(birthdate, '-%m-%d')), '%j') - 
date_format(now(), '%j') as diff
from diged_requests
having 
   diff <= 10 and diff >= 0 
   or diff + date_format(concat(year(now()), '-12-31'), '%j') <= 10 and diff < 0
order by diff
```

Il someone is born on february 29, he will not be selected on non-leap years.

Gordon's answer is simpler, it will give the n peaople with their birthday closest to today. Mine selects all people with a birthday in less than n days.

It's up to you what better fits your needs.